# parse date with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I tried to parse this string 20130718T090000Z using SimpleDateFormat. I do like this:

```
        String timeString= "20130718T090000Z";
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmssZ");
        Date date= dateFormat.parse(timeString);
```

I received an Unparsable error. Referencing from here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#rfc822timezone I found I did nothing wrong, or did I? 
Tks.

Comment: Tks all for quick and correct answers. I selected @sanbhat's one because he provides more info in his comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this format string `"yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'"` . The reason why it did not parse was, the input had not parsable character `Z` at the end. `"20130718T090000Z"`

Comment: This will not help under all circumstances as if a time with another time zone appears it will fail. The letter `Z` is used to denote the time zone.

Comment: @UwePlonus unfortunately java doesn't recognize ISO date format, so this is a way to ignore those charaters.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201925/converting-iso8601-compliant-string-to-java-util-date

Comment: I know this therefore you have to handle this manually in Java 6. Java 7 has a better support for this.

Answer (score 2):

`Z` is for Time Zone. You did not provide the time zone in the date string.

You should have done some thing like `String timeString= "20130718T090000-0700";`

In case you wanted to treat `Z` as constant then you need to change the format to `yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'`

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem that the `Z` in your time `String` is not recognized as a valid time zone.

With Java 6 you have to handle the timezone `Z` on your own and either remove it or replace it with `+0000`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to give the value of Z in your input string .
as  String timeString= "20130718T090000+0000";

This will parse your date according to the format ..

Hope it helps